# Debian Webserver and PHP Difficulties

Tags: php, apache, configuration, webserver

I resently have a problem with my webserver. I'm running
multiple vhosts on my Debian Wheezy 7 webserver.
But somehow I get an "500 Internal Server Error"  when I 
request PHP files.. for example index.php .   Also the Apache2 
error.log is empty and dosen't help me.  Everthing else works fine
*.html are shown in the webbrowser.
Does anyone have a information, where i could have a misconfiguration?
Any help would be great!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you configured mod_php or PHP-FPM? Consider asking this on server fault as this is not programming related.

Comment: I am total new to this sorry, but it should be configured with fcgid. At least what I can see. I need a start point to begin reconfiguring it. It worked before some updates where made last time.